# Embedding in navigation controller without replacing background

Tags: ios, swift

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIrft.png) is a view I presented modally

This is how it looked before i embedded this view in a navigation controller. Note, this view allows you to see the view behind it.

After embedding the view in a navigation controller, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPeuQ.png)

How can I embed this view in a nav controller without loosing view transparency to that white background?

Comment: Why do you you want to retain the Nav controller?

Comment: Why not just present it modally?

Comment: The view that you see is presented modally.  The problem with presenting views modally is that it resets navigation. I need to keep track of navigation from this view moving forward, which is why I'm embedding this view in a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

set navigation view controller's properties like below before presenting

```
modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: i tried placing that code in the viewdidload and or viewWillAppear functions. Both had no effect. I have multiple layers of views and I set them to be clear individually on storyboard. I dont think the view you are referencing above is the nav-controller view that seems to get generated. Let me know if theres more info i need to provide to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your explanation. that you embedded a navigation controller to this controller and you are presenting the navigation controller now not the view controller itself.

It supposed to work if you present the navigation controller itself modally. It will be transperant. you may only need to hide the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was change the presentation settings in the attributes inspector of the navigation controller. Once I changed it from Default to Over Current Context, I was able to get rid of the white background.